# Why are there two verbs in "The two studies were published in 2019 by A and B, both owned by C"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Why is there containing two verbs in one sentence

> The two studies were published in 2019 by A and B, both owned by C.

Comment: It's unclear what is owned by C. The two studies, or A and B? It might be better to make a sentence without letters, where the relationships are more clear.

Comment: Assuming well-edited writing, I get a strong impression that A and B are both owned by C. Otherwise it would be much clearer to say "The two studies, both owned by C, were published in 2019 by A and B." or "The two studies were published in 2019 by A and B, **and were** both owned by C."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is made up of two parts. The first part is the main clause, with the verb **were**:

> The two studies were published in 2019 by A and B

The second part of the sentence is a [participial phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm), where the participle is **owned**.

> both owned by C

Participial phrases do not contain a verb: they contain a participle, which is an adjectival form of a verb, usually ending in -ed or -ing. They can be placed before or after the main clause, and are usually separated from the main clause by a comma. They provide additional information about a noun in the main clause. Here is another example:

> Walking along the beach, Ahmed felt completely relaxed.

The main clause is "Ahmed felt completely relaxed", and the participial clause "walking along the beach" provides additional information about what Ahmed was doing.

Comment: "Both owned by C" is actually a noun phrase functioning as a supplement (or parenthetical).

Answer (score 0):

"Both owned by C" is parenthetical: consider the paraphrases

- A and B, both owned by C, published the two studies.
- A and B (both owned by C) published the two studies.

Comment: I do not really understand the use of paraphrases and cannot compose a sentence like this. What book should I read to learn more about this?

Comment: @PE This is an example of a Subordinate Clause. Don't worry too much about the word paraphrase. 'Paraphrase' just means you've reworded a sentence without changing it's meaning. The most useful terms you can search are 'subordinate clause,' 'participial phrase,' and 'participial clause.' They've all been suggested already. This answer turns the clause into a 'parenthetical' when it adds the brackets.